# REST JSON API GET Headers

Tags: json, rest

I need help in formatting the GET request for a REST JSON API.  First I have to admit I am very much a newbie in Web applications, here is my problem.  I have an application that exposes a JSON API for the parameters in my HVAC thermostat and I want to GET the data into my home automation application.  The home automation application provides a web socket interface but I have to manually send the GET request and parse the result.  I cannot see any examples on how to manually construct the request in straight text.  Here is the API documentation:

```
JSON API
Infinitive exposes a JSON API to retrieve and manipulate thermostat parameters.

GET /api/zone/1/config

{
   "currentTemp": 70,
   "currentHumidity": 50,
   "outdoorTemp": 50,
   "mode": "auto",
   "fanMode": "auto",
   "hold": true,
   "heatSetpoint": 68,
   "coolSetpoint": 74
}
```

And my Get request:

```
GET /api/zone/1/config HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.16.43:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

The response is:

```
HTTP:/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 07 Jan 2017 05:27:33 GMT
Content-Length: 5

true
```

So I guess I'm missing what parameters I want but where/how to I define that?

Many thanks

Comment: What language are you trying to create the GET request in? Or are you simply pointing your browser at a URL.

Comment: If the documentation doesn't explain then contact the manufacturer. It's not like we can randomly guess how an unknown manufacturer has decided to build their system. But anyway, content-type header in a GET request is always wrong. It doesn't have a body. Also your host header is wrong and probably not needed.

Comment: Ashhar - there is no language, except English.  I need to write the GET request in a string literal so my Home Automation program can push it out through the web socket it has opened.

Comment: Sami - There is no manufacturer, I picked up the code from the web and loaded onto my Raspberry PI.  However I don't think this is a code specific issue, it is to do with the formatting of a GET request for a JSON API, I have the details for the application specific parameters.  I see lots of examples of how to write the Java Script that will create the GET request but nothing that actually tells me how to create the straight text.  Incidentally I copied the Host header by snooper on the standard web interface in Chrome and if I do not include it I get an error so I guess it must be correct?